# Confusion in Constructor in java

Tags: java

When trying to initialize the instance variable from constructor by keeping the parameter name as instance variable name. I am receiving the output as 0. instead of the value passed. Kindly explain?

```
public class Circle
    {
         int x;
        int y;
        int radius;

    //Constructor with same parameters of field name

    public Circle(int x,int y,int radius)
    {
        x=x;
        y=y;
        radius=radius;
    }
    //Overridden to String()

    public String toString()
    {
        return "center("+x+" , "+y+") and radius ("+radius+")";
    }

    //Main method 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(new Circle(5,5,50));
    }


    }
```

When i pass values from constructor 5,5,50 to the parameters of constructor. Shouldn't they display the same value.

System.out.println(new Circle(5,5,50)); // Value sent to constructor

public Circle(int x,int y,int radius) // value to be taken by constructor parameters

Comment: What do you currently think `x=x;` does?

Comment: Change it to `this.x = x` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line `x=x;` does not have any sense because it assigns value of variable `x` into the same variable.

If you have field named `x` you should refer to it using `this` keyword: `this.x = x`. In this case you will assign value of argument `x` to member `x`.

This however does not mean that you always have to use `this` to refer to members. You have to do this if you have local variable with the same identifier it your scope.

Comment: Yes i understand that. But since i am passing value of 5,5,50 to constructor. System.out.println(new Circle(5,5,50)); Shouldn't the values passed should substitute the parameters.public Circle(int x,int y,int radius).

Comment: The values are indeed passed to your constructor. However they are not assigned to member variables. They are re-assigned again to parameters of the constructor.

Comment: Ok. But in that case when i send value to the constructor parameters then x=5,y=5,radius=50. Now inside constructor when i am trying to set the values. shouldn't the value be set as. x=5,y=5,radius=50. Sorry for exaggerating but i need to know it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Again, x=5 works in your constructor. The question is "what is `x`?" And the answer is "x is a constructor's argument". It means that in expression `x = x` you assign value of x to itself. If you want to refer to member variable use `this.x`.

Comment: Alex now i know that the local variable shadows the instance variable. So now the only thing that's left is a local variable. But there is one more question out of it. As we know local variables should be assigned to some value. It's not initialized to default values as that of instance variables. In this case i am sending values 5,5,50 to them . Not sure how they get assigned to value 0

Comment: Local variables are not assigned to 0. They are assigned to themselves. However instance variables remain to hold default values, i.e. zeros. However your `return` statement refers to the instance variables because in is context there are no other variables that shadow them. So, you actually never assign anything to instance variables and use them, that means that they hold default values, i.e. zeros.

Comment: Awesome Alex. Thanks so much i understood. The output i was getting was the default values of instance variables. As the are shadowed by local variables which have more precedence than the instance variables. Correct

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `this.x = x` etc.

The `x` passed as a parameter *shadows* the field. When this happens, you can use `this.x` to denote the field.

Comment: Ok. But in that case when i send value to the constructor parameters then x=5,y=5,radius=50. Now inside constructor when i am trying to set the values. shouldn't the value be set as. x=5,y=5,radius=50. Sorry for exaggerating but i need to know it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor's arguments hide the members of your class.

Change your constructor to:

```
public Circle(int x,int y,int radius)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.radius=radius;
}
```

Or use different names for the members and the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This is where you use `this` :

```
public Circle(int x,int y,int radius)
{
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.radius=radius;
}
```

without `this` you are actually working only on *local variables* x,y etc.

Answer (score 0):

**A Local Variable Shadows An Instance Variable**

The local variable in your constructor shadows the instance variable
Whereever you are assigning and reading an instance variable, use `this` keyword

Consider the below example

```
public class Employee{
    int id;
    String name;

public Employee(int id, String name){
    this.id = id; //sets the id to the Employee's id
    this.name = name; //sets the name to Employee's name
}
}
```

What  you have done in  your constructor will not have any effect. If you are using eclipse you can easily see a warning saying `The assignment to variable id has no effect`

When you are doing `new Circle(5,5,50))`, your constructor is just reassigning the local varaibles and not even touching the instance variable.

But when you are printing the value with `return "center("+x+" , "+y+") and radius ("+radius+")";` you are referring to the instance variables. Because there was no shadowing in your `toString` method. Thats why you are getting 0s as all the instance variables are initialized with the default values

Comment: Ok. But in that case when i send value to the constructor parameters then x=5,y=5,radius=50. Now inside constructor when i am trying to set the values. shouldn't the value be set as. x=5,y=5,radius=50. Sorry for exaggerating but i need to know it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kemparaj565 please have a look to the updated answer

Comment: Yes i do see that . Thanks shikjohari. But there is one more question out of it. As we know local variables should be assigned to some value. It's not initialized to default values as that of instance variables. In this case i am sending values 5,5,50 to them . Not sure how they get assigned to value 0.

Comment: @kemparaj565 have a look  now

Comment: Awesome!!!!!!. Shikjohari. Now i understand. Here constructor is only dealing with local variables. Its not even touching instance variables. Hence the default values are displayed.

Comment: @kemparaj565   Accept if satisfied :P